# Text at top and bottom of bubble doesn't invert side when using Right To Left langage in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Im using the JSQMessagesViewController library for my chat application and I have an issue when I try to localize it:

that is when my device is in Left To Right (LTR) language:
 [image: When my device is in Left To Right (LTR) language]

but when I try with RTL I manage to invert the bubble by changing the incomingBubble and outgoingBubble but my texts under the bubble and at the bottom remained at the same place..

[image: When my device is in Right To Left (RTL) language]

How can I taking these texts to the right place??

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a limitation of the library. You should bring up an issue on the project. But to solve the problem now there are a few things that you could do. You could subclass the Message Xib and fix it and then just use your custom xib or you can swap the bubbles based on the language direction. But this is definitely a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: thanks for answering , I already bring it up there , they listed it with questions label, I try to swap the bubble based on the langague but so far didnt succeed , if you have any insight .. also what do you mean by subclass the message XIB and fix it?